# Alert selection with mapview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, google-maps, core-location

In my app, I used core location & Mapkit framework with mapview. When wwe install the app,it shows me alert like " would like to use current location" by default without coding for the one time only. And if i select "don't allow", the map view is just shown blue background?? and if i select "ok" then it works fine.

Help me!

my code is follow:

Appdelegate.m

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager;

    CLLocation *userLocation;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];

    //=========================================Location Manager

    if(locationManager == nil)

        locationManager =[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy= kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    self.locationManager.distanceFilter= 5;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
    //==========================================
}

-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    NSLog(@"new location");

    self.userLocation=newLocation;

    NSLog(@"user llocation %f , %f",userLocation.coordinate.latitude,userLocation.coordinate.longitude);

    [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}


Mapview.h
{
IBOutlet MKMapView *map;

        CLLocation         *currentLocation;
        NSString           *specificLatitude;
        NSString           *specificLongitude;

    MKCoordinateRegion  region;
}

Mapview.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [APPDELEGATE.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
self.map.delegate = self;

    // Ensure that you can view your own location in the map view.
    [self.map setShowsUserLocation:YES];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{


    currentLocation =APPDELEGATE.userLocation;

    region.center = self.currentLocation.coordinate;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.05;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.03;
    region.span = span;
    [map setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
    [self searchPressed];

    NSLog(@"Mapview %f %f",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
          );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select "Don't Allow" then call this delegate.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
     //Do something
}
```

Comment: you should change the zoom level then show the whole map view. That alert is apple's default so we can't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but maybe you can test to see if it works.

For your view controller that displays your map view, try conforming to the UIAlertViewDelegate.

Then in the alert view delegate callback method, you can do whatever you want, if it works:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // you need to type the exact title of the alert popup
    // button index starts from 0 (left most button), so if the are 2 buttons 
    // and "Don't allow" button is on the right, the button == 1 is that button
    // the user tapped on

    if([alertView.title isEqualToString:@"Type Exact Alert Title Here"] && buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```